# How to convert adobe leonardo output array of objects into an simpler object for tailwind configuration

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, tailwind-css

I'm trying to convert the output of one library ([Adobe Leonardo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@adobe/leonardo-contrast-colors)) to a structure required by [Tailwind's `tailwind.config.js`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors#custom-colors).

The original output from Leonardo follows this structure:

```
[
  { background: "#e0e0e0" },
  {
    name: 'gray',
    values: [
      {name: "gray100", contrast: 1, value: "#e0e0e0"},
      {name: "gray200", contrast: 2, value: "#a0a0a0"},
      {name: "gray300", contrast: 3, value: "#808080"},
      {name: "gray400", contrast: 4.5, value: "#646464"}
      ...etc
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'blue',
    values: [
      {name: "blue100", contrast: 2, value: "#b18cff"},
      {name: "blue200", contrast: 3, value: "#8d63ff"},
      {name: "blue300", contrast: 4.5, value: "#623aff"},
      {name: "blue400", contrast: 8, value: "#1c0ad1"}
      ...etc
    ]
  }
]
```

In order to be useful to configure Tailwind, I would need to convert that array of objects into something that looks like this:

```
  {
    'gray': {
      "gray100": "#e0e0e0",
      "gray200": "#a0a0a0",
      "gray300": "#808080",
      "gray400": "#646464",
    },
    'blue': {
      "blue100": "#b18cff",
      "blue200": "#8d63ff",
      "blue300": "#623aff",
      "blue400": "#1c0ad1",
    }
  }
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Array.reduce` for this:

###Idea:

- Loop over data and check if object needs to be processed.
- If yes,

  - Create a local object
  - Loop over `values[i].value` and update this object with values
  - Assign this object as `acc[item.name] = object`
- If no, skip.

```js
const data = [
  { background: "#e0e0e0" },
  {
    name: 'gray',
    values: [
      {name: "gray100", contrast: 1, value: "#e0e0e0"},
      {name: "gray200", contrast: 2, value: "#a0a0a0"},
      {name: "gray300", contrast: 3, value: "#808080"},
      {name: "gray400", contrast: 4.5, value: "#646464"}
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'blue',
    values: [
      {name: "blue100", contrast: 2, value: "#b18cff"},
      {name: "blue200", contrast: 3, value: "#8d63ff"},
      {name: "blue300", contrast: 4.5, value: "#623aff"},
      {name: "blue400", contrast: 8, value: "#1c0ad1"}
    ]
  }
]

const output = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
  if ('name' in item) {
    const cssMap = {}
    item.values.forEach((value) => cssMap[value.name] = value.value)
    acc[item.name] = cssMap
  }
  return acc
}, {})

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `Array.prototype.reduce` function

```js
const input = [
  { background: "#e0e0e0" },
  {
    name: 'gray',
    values: [
      {name: "gray100", contrast: 1, value: "#e0e0e0"},
      {name: "gray200", contrast: 2, value: "#a0a0a0"},
      {name: "gray300", contrast: 3, value: "#808080"},
      {name: "gray400", contrast: 4.5, value: "#646464"}
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'blue',
    values: [
      {name: "blue100", contrast: 2, value: "#b18cff"},
      {name: "blue200", contrast: 3, value: "#8d63ff"},
      {name: "blue300", contrast: 4.5, value: "#623aff"},
      {name: "blue400", contrast: 8, value: "#1c0ad1"}
    ]
  }
];

const output = input.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  if (cur.name) {
    acc[cur.name] = cur.values.reduce((curAcc, curVal) => {
      curAcc[curVal.name] = curVal.value;
      return curAcc;
    }, {});
  }
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(output);
```